# UAC - When set to "Never notify" do I still have a dual token?

Tags: windows, uac

UAC can be set to never notify, but that's not the same as not having UAC at all.

What I mean is, does the OS still create a dual token for admin users but just auto-elevate everything?

The difference is important since various file-system ops will still behave differently to say, Windows NT 4.0.

For example, when Explorer sees a folder with only `Administrators:Full-Control` it often prompts that you don't have access and elevates, then auto-adds your user into the ACL.

That's what I seem to observe, and I really don't like it. By setting UAC to not prompt, I assume this elevate-and-modify-ACL will just happen, but its still screwing with my ACLs.

In general, since UAC, I seem to spend so much time not having rights to things and messing around with ACLs whereas in the NT 4.0 days, life was simple, the ACL was the truth.

I "get" UAC for my mother-in-law, but on a server, where experts roam?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a healthy attitude to have, in my opinion. Even experts make mistakes. Also, there are thousands of server admins in the world who I wouldn't exactly call "experts." You don't hear many *nix admins saying things like, "*man, what BS, I'm an expert, I shouldn't have to `sudo`!*"

But anyway, on to your question.

First of all, you ask, (paraphrased) *"if I disable UAC, will I still have a restricted token?"*

Well that depends. Who are you? Not everyone on the system will have a restricted token. Only users who log on to the system who are members of privileged groups such as Administrators, Domain Administrators, etc., or who have sensitive privileges such as `SeTcpPrivilege`, etc., will be given restricted tokens in addition to their full token during logon.

Please reference *Windows Internals, 6th Ed.* Part I Chapter 6 for a full list of exactly which groups and what privileges are checked before a restricted access token is generated.

A quote from the aforementioned book:

> If one or more of these groups or privileges are present, LSASS creates a restricted token for the user (also called a filtered admin token), and it creates a logon session for both. The standard user token is attached to the initial process or processes that Winlogon starts (by default, Userinit .exe) .
>
> Note If UAC has been disabled, administrators run with a token that includes their administrator group memberships and privileges.

And also, from Chapter 2 (emphasis is mine):

> Upon a successful authentication, LSASS calls a function in the security reference monitor (for example, NtCreateToken) to generate an access token object that contains the user’s security profile. **If** User Account Control (UAC) is used **and** the user logging on is a member of the administrators group or has administrator privileges, LSASS will create a second, restricted version of the token . This access token is then used by Winlogon to create the initial process(es) in the user’s session .

You can test this for yourself using `whoami /priv`. With UAC on, log on as a user who is a member of the Administrators group. In a non-elevated command prompt, you will see that the list of privileges is much shorter in the non-elevated command prompt, implying the existence of two separate tokens for the same user:

[image: UAC ON]

Now turn UAC off (or set to "Never Notify",) reboot the machine, and attempt the same test. You will notice now that there is no difference between a standard and an elevated process. No more restricted access token.

Comment: Amazing answer. If only servers really where expert only domains...

Comment: Thanks, its a brilliant answer. ...if only the "helicopter mum" features in Windows could be unilaterally turned off with a single switch. But let's not argue.